# Using a kotlin library in java code

Tags: java, android, compatibility, kotlin, aar

I have a kotlin library [FlowLayout lib as aar](https://github.com/ch4vi/FlowLayout),

and want to use it in my java code (android) but can not to resolve `kotlin.Pair`.

```
FlowLayoutManager layoutManager=new FlowLayoutManager(3, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, new FlowLayoutManager.Interface() {
    @Override
     public kotlin.Pair<Integer, Integer> getProportionalSizeForChild(int i) {
         return null;
     }
});
```

I have tried `android.support.v4.util.Pair` but is not compatible. How can I use a kotlin lib in java code with their object dependencies?

Comment: Do you have a dependency on the Kotlin library in your Java project (don't remember the artifact name, since they keep changing it, but maybe core)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Class `kotlin.Pair` belongs to the standard library `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0`, so you must have this library as a dependancy.

It is NOT recommended to use `Pair` in public APIs. Rather than that, create your own `data class` with 2 properties and give them a clearer naming than `first` and `second`.

The purpose of `Pair` is to server as a temporary data carrier in any intermediate operation. If you use it in your API, you lose in clarity.