# Using Kotlin libraries as dependencies in a Java project

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, shared-libraries

I have a library project which provides shared functionality for other projects. The implementation is written in Kotlin. However, I've ensured that the public interface of the library does not use any classes provided by Kotlin.

If we add this library as a dependency to a Java-only project, it transitively pulls in `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlin-runtime`. Classes from Kotlin-stdlib can now be potentially (but mistakenly) used in the Java-only consumer project.

Is there a way to prevent this type leakage? Some options that I can think of:

- **Mark `kotlin-stdlib-*` as `provided` in Maven:** Will this cause any issues at runtime? (`ClassNotFoundException` and such)
- **Shade + relocate `kotlin-stdlib-*` and/or `kotlin-runtime`:** With shading, I foresee issues if we depend on multiple Kotlin library projects. Also, I'm not sure if this will actually hide the Kotlin types.

Note: The question [Using a kotlin library in java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433598) does not apply here (misleading title). I specifically avoid that scenario.

Comment: It sounds more like an IDE configuration issue than a build issue. What IDE are you using? When you say that "[...] they now see ambiguous library types [...]", do you mean for autocomplete and import statements?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, my intention is to prevent Kotlin stdlib classes from being available in the Java project. Everything else is cosmetic.

Comment: If they're not available, how can your Kotlin library use them?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, yes, that's the rub. I can't think of a way to encapsulate these dependencies so they are only available to my library implementation (Java 9 modules, anyone?).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't declaring your library dependencies using `implementation` keyword enough for not exposing them transitively ? like stated [here](https://guides.gradle.org/building-kotlin-jvm-libraries/) `We use the implementation dependency configuration so that we don’t expose any of the Kotlin standard library through our API. This has architectural and performance benefits.`

Comment: The `implementation` keyword is specific to Gradle, right? I'm looking for a Maven solution (see tags).